# Make a textbox's text not editable but viewable in runtime

Tags: winforms, textbox

I want to make my textbox display the text "Username" or "Password" but when the user starts typing it in it starts editing that text. I want that text to then disappear.

[the image of what Im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dWjR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Visual Basic or C# for this? Regardless, Visual Studio should have a "PlaceholderText" option under the "Properties" menu on the right-hand side when you click on your text box.

[image: Visual Studio Properties Window]

Comment: kasprdev that is a better method honestly but I figured another way out... :) . I called the event on "mouseClick". And when its clicked the text is set to " ". It works honestly Im okay with it. Thanks for the suggestion!